# Python - Reveal a COM object

Tags: python, email, com, python-3.3

```
import win32com.client
outlook=win32com.clent.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages=inbox.Items
message.messages.GetLast()
body_content=message.Body
print(body_content)
```

This will print the body of an email in my inbox.  What I want to do is to reveal what is happening at each stage of this code so that I may better understand it, however when I try to print inbox, messages I get:

```
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

How do I reveal this so that I can begin to see what I'm working with.

I'm also looking for a place which has clear documentation surrounding using python to interact with MS Outlook, if anyone can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221870(v=office.11).aspx

In the outlook object model, most objects have a `Class` property, which returns an enumeration of type `OlObjectType`, saying what type of object it is. Other properties common to outlook (and indeed MS Office) object are `Parent` and `Application`.

If you really want to, it should be easy enough to make a function `describe_outlook_object` which returns a string with useful information. You will have to write it yourself of course.

Alternatively if you just want to explore the object model, you could do worse than hit Alt+F11 in Outlook and have a play with Visual Basic. (You will have to enable macros.)

Comment: I tried accessing the Class property and it is just an "int", not a list. Isn't there a way to ask for a list of all attributes that are present? (The link gives a webpage with just a generic structure.) Any ideas on how to retrieve the list?

Comment: @MichelJanssens It is not a list of properties. The `Class` property is a COM type enumeration, which is essentially an int with a set of named constants. The value identifies the class. Check the documentation for the meanings of the values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211793(v=office.11)#olobjectclass

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment yet, but wanted to add to Ben's answer (which helped me immensely in a similar situation)

I wanted a way to scrape emails from multiple PST files/accounts in Outlook

```
import win32com.client

outlook_object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

namespace = outlook_object.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# collection of accounts
accounts = namespace.Folders

# number of outlook accounts
accounts_count = accounts.Count

# .Item(1) not .Item(0) because counting starts at 1
account1 = accounts.Item(1)

# collection of folders for account1
account_folders = account1.Folders
# number of folders under outlook account
account_folders_count = account_folders.Count

# print account1 folder names
for folder in range(account_folders_count):
    # must be +1 because .Folder(0) and .Item(0) do not work
    print str(folder+1)+":", account_folders.Item(folder+1)
```

There is a pattern to using `Folders.Count` and `Folders.Item(1)` to get down to the messages.  Hopefully this helps someone, because it took me hours of googling to get to this point.