# Change the 'From' field in Outlook mail item

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to automate a mass e-mailing and need to change the 'From' field in Outlook.  The e-mail cannot be ['Sent on Behalf of'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454538/choosing-from-field-using-python-win32com-outlook) per compliance reasons.  When I attempted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618725/python-automated-outlook-email-change-sender-or-default-reply-to-address), I received the following error...

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

This error is referencing the `mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, email_from))` line.  Code snippet is below.  Let me know what I have wrong or if there is a better way.

```
to = 'jsmith@external_domain.com'
cc = 'my_group_e-mail@my_domain.com'
subject = personalized_subject_from_data_source
body = f'''personalized body from other data source with a {table}'''

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
# adding the code suggested by h0r53:
email_from = None
for account in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if account.DisplayName == 'why_i_asked_email@my_domain.com':
        email_from = account
        break
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
# email_from = 'why_i_asked_email@my_domain.com'
mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, email_from))
mail.To = to
mail.CC = cc
mail.Subject = subject
mail.HTMLbody = body
mail.Display(True)
```

**EDIT**
After adding the code suggested by h0r53, I still receive the same error.  the variable `account` is listed as `<COMObject <unknown>>` and thus never satisfies the logic gate and when the `for` iteration completes, `email_from == None` and thus throws the same error.  Any further help is appreciated

Thanks!!

Comment: `email_from` likely isn't supposed to be a `String` at all, but rather an object that represents a domain user. In the solution you referenced, the `email_from` variable is NOT a string, but rather an entry in `outlook_app.Session.Accounts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with this: [Python - Reveal a COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000808/python-reveal-a-com-object).  In the `for` method, it is not `outlook.Session.Accounts`, rather it is `outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI').Accounts` as below:

```
    for account in outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI').Accounts:
        if str(account) == 'the_e-mail_in_question':
            email_from = account
            break
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, email_from))
    mail.To = to
    mail.CC = cc
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HTMLbody = body
    mail.Display(True)
```